# HSTS max-age not set properly after redirection from Azure B2C authentication

Tags: azure, hsts, azure-ad-b2c

I am facing an issue while configuring HSTS on a web app that uses Azure B2C for authentication/authorization. To put things in context, the web app was originally configured with HSTS `max-age=31536000`. But HSTS guidelines advise to start with a low value and then increment it bit by bit. So I lowered it to `max-age=3600`.

Here's what's happening right now, step by step (I'll refer to this as **scenario 1**):

1. Navigate to the web app at `my-web-app.azurewebsites.net`
2. A request is made to an authorization endpoint provided by Azure B2C (something like `https://myazuretenant.b2clogin.com/myazuretenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`).
3. If I'm not authorized (first visit or token expired), redirection to a login page (something like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/myazuretenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize`)
4. Upon successful login, redirection to the web app at `my-web-app.azurewebsites.net`

Now in that case, everything is as expected: when I check the redirection request made to my web app on step 4, the HSTS header has the expected value with `max-age=3600`.

The issue arises when I am already authorized. Again step by step (**scenario 2**):

1. Navigate to the web app at `my-web-app.azurewebsites.net`.
2. A request is made to the Azure B2C authorization endpoint.
3. I am authorized and redirected to the web app directly without going through the login page.

In this scenario, on step 3, my HSTS header has `max-age=31536000`. At first I figured maybe there was an issue where the new decreased value of `max-age` was being ignored (some kind of caching maybe).

But upon closer inspection, I noticed that the request to my web app on step 3 has the exact same headers and values as the authorization request from step 2, such as `Location` for the redirect, `Set-Cookie`, `Allow`, etc. none of which were present on step 4 in scenario 1.

So is it at all possible that the headers from the auth request were somehow "copied" or "inherited" when being redirected to my web app?

Interestingly enough, this isn't the case on Firefox where I do get `max-age=3600` on step 3 of scenario 2 and the same headers as step 4 of scenario 1.